# Location of networking config file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

There is a file in which I can set from what interfaces dhcp can provide ip and etc.
there was a line like  this `interface = "eth0 eth1"`

What is the file's name?

Comment: This sort of basic question is better suited to [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com)

Answer (score 4):

The file you're looking for is: `/etc/network/interfaces`

You can find a reference for the structure of this file by taking a look at `/usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples/network-interfaces` and also in the [online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html).

Comment: I set static ip in `interfaces`. but in the file the was only one like `interfaces=""`

Comment: What your answer is accurate, I suspect you are miss-understanding the question.  I can understand why you might do that, it isn't entirely clear.

Comment: @ArtemTsarionov could you please edit your question to be more clear as to what exactly you're trying to do? Are you trying to set up a DHCP server, or are you trying to set up a PC with a static/dynamic IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but allow me to but on my mind reading cap for a bit and make a few guesses.

I am guessing that you are running the ISC DHCPd server that comes as a package.  It has several files related to the configuration and startup

- /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf : Main configuration file
- /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server : Startup script
- /etc/default/dhcp3-server : A bash fragment that that is sourced by the startup script.

An example `/etc/default/dhcp3-server` config file

```
# Defaults for dhcp initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
# installed at /etc/default/dhcp3-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth0"
#INTERFACES="eth1"
```